# su -l root permission denied

Tags: su

I have centos7 as a virtual box on windows 7. Besides root, I created another user "john" during that time. Some time later, I forgot my root password and reset it my going to single user prompt. Since then whenever I login as "john" I am not able to do `su -l root`. I get `permission denied`. I logged in as root and changed sudoer file with the following:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
admin ALL=/bin/su
Defaults: admin rootpw
john ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I then added john to wheel group and updated `/etc/pam.d/su` with:

```
auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

Also,I am not able to do `su -l john` when I am logged in as "root".
Any help here is appreciated.

`/var/log/secure` shows:

```
Mar 6 .... localhost su: PAM(other) no module name supplied
Mar 6 .....localhost su: PAM(other) illegal module type: @include
Mar 6 .....localhost su: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value: [...common-session]
```

Manny

Comment: If you're using `su`, then editing `/etc/sudoers` is pointless. The two are completely unrelated.

Comment: Use `sudo` instead. The `sudoers` file is the configuration for `sudo`, not for `su`.

Comment: It looks that you might have some misconfiguration in PAM. Check /etc/pam.d for recent changes. Check for `su` and `su-l` files first. Log indicates that something is messed up there around 'include' keyword.

Comment: I added john to root group. I can now do sudu -s. However, sudo su -l root still gives permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you might have some misconfiguration in PAM. Check /etc/pam.d for recent changes. For a fast check you could do something like:

```
for i in /etc/pam.d/* ; do rpm -qf $i; done | sort -u | sed -e 's/-[0-9]*.*//' | while read p; do echo "Verrifing package $p"; rpm -V $p ; done
```

This will basically print all packages that owns files in /etc/pam.d. Next I use sed to remove version marks from them and in last I use rpm -V which compares files on disk with those in rpm packages.

If any change is detected it will be printed on screen in form:

```
S.5....T.  c /etc/pam.d/su-l
```

Meaning of flags are as follows (`man rpm`)

```
S file Size differs
M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
5 digest (formerly MD5 sum) differs
D Device major/minor number mismatch
L readLink(2) path mismatch
U User ownership differs
G Group ownership differs
T mTime differs
P caPabilities differ
```

If you find changed files, you can examine it to check if changes are made by you and there are errors or not. You might want to move problematic configuration file and reinstall package owning it with `yum reinstall pkg_name`.

Comment: fixed with updating /etc/pam.d/su to this - #%PAM-1.0
auth  sufficient pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth  sufficient pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth  required pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth  substack system-auth
auth  include  postlogin
account  sufficient pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account  include  system-auth
password include  system-auth
session  include  system-auth
session  include  postlogin
session  optional pam_xauth.so